# How to control events in a Google Calendar from a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

Dear StackOverflow community! Today I seek your help to solve a problem. After days of search and trials with available material on the web, I state with a certainty that if found, the solution might help not only me but a bunch of people out there who struggle to find an answer to the following question:

How to control events in a Google Calendar from a Google spreadsheet?

To define "control", I hereby outline some key features of the spreadsheet/calendar integration:

1. The spreadsheet collects data from submitted forms.
2. The database of responses is then organized on a separate sheet with the help of QUERY.
3. Unsolved: the QUERYed data become calendar events upon command. Just imagine a secretary who comes to work every morning, opens a spreadsheet, clicks 'refresh', and the calendar displays new events (submitted by partners via the survey forms while she was resting).
4. Events can last for several hours or several days.
5. Because events are organized by different organizations, several events can start and end at the same time. Hence, titles of events (somehow) should start with an organization's name to distinguish it from other overlapping events.

Here is a [link](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0_Q6qg8f75Ls/?hl=en) to my original post with links to associated files and researched material on the subject.

Comment: So what is the actual problem you're facing? You want to know how to create calendar events based on your spreadsheet data? With regard to your question how to "control" your calendar from a spreadsheet: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/)

Comment: @Casper I’m looking for a ready-made solution not to invent the wheel again. Thanks,

Comment: If you are just looking for an add-on and not wanting to create the app yourself, check the add-on store for [sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create?addon_store) or [forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/create?addon_store)

Comment: @random-parts no I’m not looking for an add-on. I’m looking for an available solutions that use google script